# Setup react fronted + node express as backend - 405

Tags: nginx

i have project structure as

```
/var/www/html/server.js - express node api
/var/www/html/client/build/ - react npm run build
/var/www/html/client/package.json and other files
```

My nginx config

```
server {
    server_name myEC2ip;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/client/build/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

   location /var/www/html/ {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://myEc2IP:5000;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

I am getting 405 error - What is making wrong?

Comment: Please add relevant nginx logs to the question.

Comment: @EdwardTeach rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"